# Deduce lambda expression in a template function call C++

Tags: c++, templates

I try the following piece of code

```
template <typename T>
void call_with(std::function<void(T)> f, T val)
{
   f(val);
}
int main()
{
    auto print = [] (int x) { std::cout << x; };
    call_with<int>(print, 42);
}
```

This code successfully compiles because compiler explicitly convert T to int

But I try the following

```
template <typename T, T val>
void call_with(std::function<void(T)> f)
{
   f(val);
}
int main()
{
    auto print = [] (int x) { std::cout << x; };
    call_with(print, 42); 
}
```

This code does not compile. Why the T is not deduced to int?
The error that is produced is

> no matching function for call to 'call_with(main()::&, int)'  >Templates.cpp  /PlayWithTemplates  line 527

The third try it was to create a help struct template

```
struct Identity
{
 typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
using Identity_t = typename Identity<T>::type;

template <typename T>
void call_with(std::function<void(Identity_t<T>)> f, T val)
{
  f(val);
}

int main() 
{
   auto print = [] (int x) { std::cout << x; };
    call_with(print, 42);
}
```

This piece of code does not compile as well
The error that is printed is

> > invalid argument

Give me a hint please

Comment: The third code compiles using gcc and clang assuming you add the missing `template <typename T>` and used headers, of course. The second code doesn't make any sense as you have a function taking one argument being called with two arguments. Even when fixing that the code won't compile, though, as the type `T` needs to be deduced before the default argument is considered (... and, BTW, I don't think any of what I wrote in this comment is covered in the question this is allegedly a duplicate of).

Comment: Thank you for your point. I try to compile using minGW compiler and always fails. But trying this using GCC compiles and compiles successfully.